# How to get tag of label with user tap gestures in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

How can i get which label is being tapped from a loop of labels. I have 4 labels in a loop and i want if i click on label whose tag is 3 i should got an other label appear on view which is already hidden, how can i get this?

```
CGFloat y1 = 100.0;
CGFloat x1 = 30.0;
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, 100, 30);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
label.tag = 4+i;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self.view addSubview:label];

    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, y1,  50, 30)];
    label2.tag = 100+i;
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    label2.text = @"World";
     label2.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:label2];
    rect1.origin.y += 45;
}
```

}

```
   -(void)gotTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
   for (UILabel *v in label2) {
    v.hidden = !v.hidden;
   switch(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)
        {
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 2");
                break;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**updated answer**.

u did some wrong co-ordinates  in ur code check it for label 2 :

```
y1=y1+45;// extra line u need to add




CGFloat y1 = 40;
CGFloat x1 = 30.0;
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, 100, 30);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    label.tag = i+1;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, y1,  50, 30)];

    label2.tag = i+100;
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:8];
    label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld",@"world",(long)label2.tag];
    label2.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:label2];
    rect1.origin.y += 45;
    y1=y1+45;

    NSLog(@"tag values of label2 are %ld",label2.tag);

}
```

**// UITapGestureRecognizer actions**

```
-(void)gotTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {


    NSLog(@"%ld",(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag));

    int num= 99 +(int)(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag);
    NSLog(@"%d",num);

    UILabel *label3 = [self.view viewWithTag:num];
    label3.hidden = NO;


           switch(((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)
        {
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 1");



                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 2");
                NSLog(@"%ld",100 +((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) ;

                break;
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 3");
                NSLog(@"%ld",100 +((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) ;

                break;
            case 4:
                NSLog(@"Clicked on label 4");
                NSLog(@"%ld",100 +((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) ;

                break;

        }
}
```

Comment: yes it is working fine for showing log which label is clicked but if i want to get my hidden label when click on label with tag 3 how can i got?

Comment: can you please update your answer for my hidden labels then i will accept and upvote you thanks.

Comment: see it label2 is hidden initially

Comment: @Alex. check now .. I updated answer I think it will fulfil u r requirement

Comment: it is giving with all labels touch i want hidden label appear only when touch label having tag 3 not for all

Comment: i mean if(label.tag==3){ // hidden label appear and so on for other labels

Comment: can u specify clearly sorry I did't get it use label and label2

Comment: i actually want to perform action against all the tags of label

Comment: if u click on ur label of tag 3 .. what u need to hide ?? all label u need to hide or label2 labels ???

Comment: i have 4 labels in loop named as label and 4 other hidden labels named as label2 which is hidden initially now i want if i click on label whose tag is 1 my label2 should appear and so on for all labels individually

Comment: in this case hidden label2 is 4 in counting but when i click on label i got only one label